# Wait until In App Purchase is complete until perform actions

Tags: ios, swift, storekit, swiftystorekit

When a button is pressed I use storekit to purchase it. But the issue is the createItems() function and segue are performed before the purchase is confirmed. Is there any way to do this?

```
func addItems() { 
    IAPService.shared.purchase(product: .nonConsumable)
    createItems()
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "returnItems", sender: self) 
}
```

I need the function + segue to be run after the in app purchase has been completed.

IAP function:

```
func purchase(product: IAPProduct) {
    guard let productToPurchase = products.filter({ $0.productIdentifier == product.rawValue}).first else {return}
    let payment = SKPayment(product: productToPurchase)
    paymentQueue.add(payment)
}
```

payment Queue function

```
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    for transaction in transactions {
        print(transaction.transactionState.status(), transaction.payment.productIdentifier)
        switch transaction.transactionState {
        case .purchasing:
            break
        default:
            queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: post `IAPService.shared.purchase`

Comment: updated the post

Comment: `paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])` — this delegate method is triggered after calling the purchaseProduct(index: Int) function. In this callback, you will get everything related to the IAP transaction ( like if an item has been purchased or it failed)

Comment: embed the segue code inside it's purchased state

Comment: How do I do this if its a completely different class?

Comment: Then provide a callback so that the completely different class has a way of telling you that the purchase has occurred.

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution is for the `paymentQueue` method, when it is called because the purchase has taken place, to post a Notification thru the NotificationCenter. Any other view controller that needs to be informed instantly when the purchase takes place will have registered for this Notification, and thus will hear about it at that moment and can take any desired action.

Keep in mind, too, that you are going to record somewhere, typically in UserDefaults, the fact that the purchase has occurred. Thus any subsequent view controller can always check in its `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` to see whether the purchase has happened, and can modify its behavior accordingly.